# TensorFlow keeps consuming system memory and stuck during training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I was trying to train a small network to get familiar with TensorFlow 2.0. However, it seems that tensorflow does not work properly on my computer.
Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from functools import reduce
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Sequential, datasets
import numpy as np




(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()


train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0


class Model():
   weights = []
   biases = []

   def weights_collect(self):
       for l in self.layers:
           try:
               self.weights.append(l.kernel)
               self.biases.append(l.bias)
           except:
               pass

   def __init__(self):
       self.layers = [
           layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
           layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2)),
           layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
           layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2)),
           layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
           layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2)),
           layers.Flatten(),
           layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
           layers.Dense(10)
       ]
       self.model = Sequential(self.layers)
       self.weights_collect()

   @tf.function
   def predict_logits(self, X):
       return self.model(X)


   @tf.function
   def __call__(self, X):
       return tf.nn.softmax(self.model(X))


@tf.function
def loss(m:Model, x:np.ndarray, t:np.ndarray):
   logits = m.predict_logits(x)
   tar = tf.one_hot(t, 10)
   return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(tar, logits))

@tf.function
def acc(m, X, T):
   logits = m.predict_logits(X)
   target = tf.reshape(tf.dtypes.cast(T, tf.dtypes.int32), [-1])
   pred = tf.math.argmax(logits, axis=1, output_type=tf.dtypes.int32)
   return tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.dtypes.cast(pred==target, tf.dtypes.int32))/tf.shape(X)[0]


BATCH_SIZE = 1
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels)).batch(BATCH_SIZE)


m = Model()
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
EPOCHS = 20
for i in range(EPOCHS):
   for x, t in dataset:
       with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
           loss_value = loss(m, x, t)
       grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, m.model.trainable_weights)
       opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, m.model.trainable_weights))
       print("hello")
   print(float(loss(m, test_images, test_labels)))
   print(float(acc(m, test_images, test_labels)))
```

When running this code, I kept getting this kind of error message:

```
Allocation of 1228800000 exceeds 10% of system memory.
```

And my model will stop training after this.

I have tried to change the batch size, but it still does not work. Model got trained for several iterations and died. Even I have changed the batch size to 1.

It seems that TensorFlow keeps allocating system memory during training while does not release it.

I have also reinstalled the entire system trying to fix this, and it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Just got the problem solved, it seems that there is something wrong with the latest version of NVIDIA's Game Ready Driver(440.97). As soon as I roll back to 436.48, code will continue training even though the error I mentioned above will still present.

Answer (score 1):

Which GPU you are using in your computer? Your code works fine with a GPU card in it. I increased the batch size to 128 and removed the `print('Hello')` statement and then I was successfully able to run the code.

Also, since you are just getting started with TensorFlow, `GradientTape` is not the way to start learning TensorFlow. It is used only for customized training. Make use of [`model.fit()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) to perform training or else start with these official [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification).

Answer (score 0):

I have also had a problem training a MaskRCNN model using the tensorflow object detection api (it would just hang after the first step, no GPU usage and a constant ~18 CPU). The script worked fine a fortnight ago.

Long story short, I rolled back to the driver suggested and it all works well again. I also tried the latest update (the one after 440.97), and the problem was still there.

Answer (score 0):

i was suffering from the same issue for a many weeks and finally

i got that

i ran using window10 and windows server 
using powershell
" .\nvidia-smi  -q -i 0 -d SUPPORTED_CLOCKS"
**and see that NVidia driver is using Cuda 10.2**
when try to downgrade my NVIDIA DRIVER to Cuda 10.1 or CUDA 10.0 it finally worked 
seem there is an issue with Supported CUDA10.2
[image]